# QGIS Server Catalog URL

Tags: qgis-server, catalog-service

I'm trying to set up [QGIS Server Catalog](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/catalog.html) but can't make it work. QGIS Server 3.22 runs correctly using the default setup with [nginx and systemd](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#systemd).

I use this QGIS Server environment variables to set up a Catalog landing page:

```
QGIS_SERVER_LANDING_PAGE_PREFIX /catalog;
QGIS_SERVER_LANDING_PAGE_PROJECTS_DIRECTORIES /home/qgis/projects;
```

The example project doesn't use PostgreSQL so `QGIS_SERVER_LANDING_PAGE_PROJECTS_PG_CONNECTIONS` should not be necessary.

So what should be the URL to reach the catalog? QGIS Server endpoint is `http://localhost/qgisserver` but neither `http://localhost/catalog` nor `http://localhost/qgisserver/catalog` do work.

Should it run out of the box or do I have to make some additional configuration, like setting a location at *nginx.conf*?

Comment: try https://github.com/elpaso/qgis-server-landing-page-plugin

Comment: Thanks, I do know the original plugin repo, but actually it is in core since 3.16 (and available as qgis-server-landingpage on most distros). But it seems to me that I have to configure the endpoint or start the service somehow to make it work...